# Javascript 'For' loop debugging BEGINNER

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm learning JavaScript and need help in making this work. I believe the `for loop` is the issue but I don't understand. This is just making my browser freeze up.

```
var formatNumber = function(num, type) {

   var numSplit, int, dec;

   num = Math.abs(num);
   num = num.toFixed(2); 
   numSplit =  num.split('.');
   int = numSplit[0];

   **if (int.length > 3) {
    for (var i = 3; i < int.length; i + 4) {
        int = int.substr(0,int.length - i) + ',' + int.substr(int.length - i, int.length);
        }
    };** 


   dec = numSplit[1];


   return (type === 'exp' ? sign = '-' : sign = '+') + '' + int + dec;

};
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it using the browser's debugging tools? By doing so you'll be able to inspect the value contained on every variable you've used and figure out what's happening on your code yourself. Good luck.

Comment: You probably meant `i += 4` instead of `i + 4`?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will not increment and therefor `i` will always be `< int.length`. Use an addition assignment `+=` to increase the value of `i` with 4.

```
for (var i = 3; i < int.length; i += 4) {
  int = int.substr(0,int.length - i) + ',' + int.substr(int.length - i, int.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to remove ** and possibly change  i + 4  to i+-4.

To format a number with commas you can start with the following function and develop it further:

```js
function formatNumCommas(num) {
return num.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

console.log(formatNumCommas(1000));      // "1,000"
console.log(formatNumCommas(1000.234));  // "1,000.234"
console.log(formatNumCommas(12345.234)); // "12,345.234"
console.log(formatNumCommas("text"));    // text
```